# Mark multiple component properties as deprecated depending on value type

Tags: typescript, jsx, typescript-typings

I am looking for a way to add highlighting of deprecated properties to React component when some of them are deprecated and some of them are not ([demo at TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcARFATIwNwBQnA9D3GWrAAduRgBPMEgDO3CVLgARJGBZoUMJCQDKYdCIDmAFUnkAvHGkwohzvPKEkAd137hx03AvCAriABGSFDcIppQ1OjkAJLCYcIoADYACnRg0riccFlwaAAWwAkkLMIA-ABccACCUFAo4gA8KMLiAHxcFHKeKRBpAOrAMLkAQijSSK5ohl5wMXGJ3WlwAGQZ2XAwPeVwji56k%204mUlxr-hAwGyBbOxOGh0jtXLwAVE9wAAJkqkjqmiRwTzw7F1UtJ%20oNlF8flobu5prMgvFkiDlqtsjwXu9PmoNFp-oC1hswFsIdjfjCPEdMmiMR8VKTcQCqVlTud6MS6d8cTo9rdTA9OgoAMIQWIoERBBbpCw4JlwAAUqh60gqkrBw1G4x5sJWMrWaxY1C2AAkjABZAAyimAADcAKIJJAgJCxOAAHzgvgSCWO2QoAEoKsh0DBiGQfVkFSCVSC1STOWStQYUbq9VkDcazZabfbHc74O7Pd7Zf7A6xQ-dZSRgNIwAk6oQUE6tlYbO5%20bx%20IJxXBhaLxcFOGgRVYeyKYGLRFAKr3x-3JdM5X6vC1cHAWDAfFBhHB6lXrTwVx0O5ZchAnDBQEhuEPhCOAKoBFhelAzidBBd%20fxPuuSravucgkuZgrimaZIBuW47i0sprHwcCJAkcCKosuQoNa5DCNAICJHA1qJD4Mgwdk9T-pO6w9GYOAAIxUCyFyUQATFQB5EVkcEIUhyKoehAgclCfx4QkBHpE0fwoCwnE9EECTiHA2FQAA1rioy8ZCXKsTupHvoSZgAOQoLpcB0fQen%20LpLGpmx-BDAgADyADStqEJJYC4fhMhwNx5AsrkHpYThomqfSAnubIlmaWOb5QORYCUTRRlnPRulmRZllwTZDlOZYXwoFWsLIWFlkkZF-a4AAdBVn7figkoUKlWT1CxR71A%20X5IM%20WlQCxQA) is available).

Let's imagine, there is a `Container` component that has `top` and `bottom` properties, that define spacing from the top and from the bottom of container. These properties used to be a string, now I want them to be numbers.

```
type DeprecatedSpacingType = string
type NewSpacingType = number

interface InternalProps {
    children?: Array<any>;
}

type PropsWithBaseSpacing = InternalProps & {
    top?: NewSpacingType;
    bottom?: NewSpacingType;
};

/** @deprecated */
type PropsWithDeprecatedSpacing = InternalProps & {
    /** @deprecated */
    top?: DeprecatedSpacingType;
    /** @deprecated */
    bottom?: DeprecatedSpacingType;
};

type ContainerProps = {
    (props: PropsWithBaseSpacing & {
        ref?: HTMLDivElement | null;
    }): ReactNode;
    (props: PropsWithDeprecatedSpacing & {
        ref?: HTMLDivElement | null;
    }): ReactNode;
    displayName?: string;
};

// Deprecated way
<Container top='aaa' bottom='bbb' />

// New way
<Container top={111} bottom={222} />
```

I want to highlight these properties **only when they have deprecated value** used (strings) and I want it to be possible to use properties of **different types** in the same component.

```
<Container top='aaa' bottom={222} />
```

As it turns out, it is not possible due to the error below

[image: error screenshot]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please see [the demo at TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcARFATIwNwBQnA9D3GWrAAduRgBPMEgDO3CVLgARJGBZoUMJCQDKYdCIDmAFUnkAvHGkwohzvPKEkAd137hx03AvCAriABGSFDcIppQ1OjkAJLCYcIoADYACnRg0riccFlwaAAWwAkkLMIA-ABccACCUFAo4gA8KMLiAHxcFHKeKRBpAOrAMLkAQijSSK5ohl5wMXGJ3WlwAGQZ2XAwPeVwji56k%204mUlxr-hAwGyBbOxOGh0jtXLwAVE9wAAJkqkjqmiRwTzw7F1UtJ%20oNlF8flobu5prMgvFkiDlqtsjwXu9PmoNFp-oC1hswFsIdjfjCPEdMmiMR8VKTcQCqVlTud6MS6d8cTo9rdTA9OgoAMIQWIoERBBbpCw4JlwAAUqh60gqkrBw1G4x5sJWMrWaxY1C2AAkjABZAAyimAADcAKIJJAgJCxOAAHzgvgSCWO2QoAEoKsh0DBiGQfVkFSCVSC1STOWStQYUbq9VkDcazZabfbHc74O7Pd7Zf7A6xQ-dZSRgNIwAk6oQUE6tlYbO5%20bx%20IJxXBhaLxcFOGgRVYeyKYGLRFAKr3x-3JdM5X6vC1cHAWDAfFBhHB6lXrTwVx0O5ZchAnDBQEhuEPhCOAKoBFhelAzidBBd%20fxPuuSravucgkuZgrimaZIBuW47i0sprHwcCJAkcCKosuQoNa5DCNAICJHA1qJD4Mgwdk9T-pO6w9GYOAAIxUCyFyUQATFQB5EVkcEIUhyKoehAgclCfx4QkBHpE0fwoCwnE9EECTiHA2FQAA1rioy8ZCXKsTupHvoSZgAOQoLpcB0fQen%20LpLGpmx-BDAgADyADStqEJJYC4fhMhwNx5AsrkHpYThomqfSAnubIlmaWOb5QORYCUTRRlnPRulmRZllwTZDlOZYXwoFWsLIWFlkkZF-a4AAdBVn7figkoUKlWT1CxR71A%20X5IM%20WlQCxQA)